# Trouble starting Rails server on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I want to use Rails 4.2.3 and i managed to install it using rbenv and gem. When starting the server i get this error:

```
rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.3 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
/Users/macuser/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/Users/macuser/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
Exiting
/Users/macuser/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
    from /Users/macuser/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /Users/macuser/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /Users/macuser/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /Users/macuser/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /Users/macuser/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /Users/macuser/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /Users/macuser/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /Users/macuser/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
     ... 5542 levels...
    from /Users/macuser/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/macuser/dreamer_me/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Swards.

rbenv versions
  system
* 2.4.0 (set by /Users/macuser/.rbenv/version)

Where can i find .ruby-version? By app level do you mean in the directory created when running "rails new"

Comment: Yes, add the .ruby-version (that's the file name, with the .) at the same level as /app.  Then you can add a ruby by doing rbenv install - e.g. `rbenv install 2.2.2`

Answer (score 1):

You're running Ruby 2.4, you can change your ruby version by setting it in `.ruby-version` file at the app level.

```
# .ruby-version
2.2.2
```

Or whatever you like.  You can see what ruby versions you have available

```
$ rbenv versions
```

Comment: The problem here is that i had mixed the latest version of Ruby with an early version Rails and the two didn't match quite well. It looks like Rails had requested *Fixnum* and *Bignum* which have deprecated as of version 2.4.
I think any version earlier than 2.4 before those two were deprecated can work. I uninstalled Ruby 2.4.0 and installed Ruby 2.2.2 and it worked.

**Shout out to @Swards for helping me out**.